# Chrome is trying to load fonts from Cache after updating to version 74. Any implementation changes in latest version?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Font files returns 200 from disk cache without the actual fonts, so fonts are not loading. In earlier versions, each time it was returning 304. I am loading the fonts thought font-face as below.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: RobotoLight;
    src: url('/stylesheets/fonts/Light/Roboto-Light-webfont.eot?i=1#iefix');
    src: url('/stylesheets/fonts/Light/Roboto-Light-webfont.eot?i=1#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/stylesheets/fonts/Light/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff?i=1#iefix') format('woff'),
     url('/stylesheets/fonts/Light/Roboto-Light-webfont.ttf?i=1#iefix') format('truetype'),
     url('/stylesheets/fonts/Light/Roboto-Light-webfont.svg#RobotoLight') format('svg');
}
```